# Cannot acces WSO2 API Manager Publisher after adding API Manager Feature in ESB

Tags: http, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I'm new to WSO2 products and the company I worked for asked me to evaluate WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus (ESB). Aside from this they also wanted to evaluate the WSO2 Identity Server (IS) and WSO2 API Manager (APIM). So we created a test system installing ESB as the base product. After researching most of the references in the web states that you can install other WSO2 products inside an existing one by installing it's feature. So we decided that approach and after a few issues we have successfully installed APIM and IS inside a running ESB. However while accessing the APIM Publisher by using the url https://:9443/publisher we got an error

```
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

type Status report

message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

Any idea what happened as we have not seen any errors on the logs? Is it possible if I just install on a separate instance the WSO2 APIM but assigning it to a different port so as to avoid conflict with the ESB?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible if I just install on a separate instance the WSO2 APIM
>   but assigning it to a different port so as to avoid conflict with the
>   ESB?

Port offset allows you to run multiple WSO2 products, multiple instances of a WSO2 product, or multiple WSO2 product clusters on the same server or virtual machine (VM). Port offset defines the number by which all ports defined in the runtime such as the HTTP/S ports will be offset.

For example, if the default HTTP port is 9763 and the portOffset is 1, the effective HTTP port will be 9764. Therefore, for each additional WSO2 product instance, set the port offset to a unique value (the default is 0) so that they can all run on the same server without any port conflicts.

Port offset can be passed to the server during startup. The following command starts the server with the default port incremented by 3.

```
./wso2server.sh -DportOffset=3
```

Alternatively, you can set it in the Ports section of `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` as follows:

```
<Offset>3</Offset>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the contingency plan that I was thinking about. Thank you for verifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You dont need to install API manager features in the ESB. You can take a API Manager instance instead which has a lightweight ESB running inside. you can access this from the management console on the API Manager

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I'll try to install it separately. Thanks again.